# Add dynamic methods to the class.methods array

Tags: ruby

I am creating dynamic methods using the **method_missing** function.
Its all working fine, but the thing i wanna do is, add these methods to **ClassName.methods** array. The code is as follows:

```
module MyObjectStore
  values = []
  temp =  {}
  def self.included(kls)
    kls.extend ClassMethods
  end

  ClassMethods = Module.new do
    define_method :method_missing do |method,*args,&block|          
      if method =~ /find_by_/
        methods << method
        add_search_method(method,*args)
      else
        values.send "#{method}", &block
      end
    end
    define_method :add_search_method do |method,*args|
      values.each do |obj|
        x = obj.send "#{method.to_s.split('_')[-1]}"
        if x == args[0]
          p obj
        end
      end
    end
  end

  define_method :add_check_attribute do |method,*args|
    if method.to_s =~ /=$/
      temp[method[0..-2]] = args[0]
    else
      instance_variable_get("@#{method}")
    end
  end
  define_method :method_missing do |method,*args|
    add_check_attribute(method,*args)
  end
  define_method :save do
    temp.each {|key,value| instance_variable_set("@#{key}",value)}
    values << self
  end
end

class C
  include MyObjectStore
end
```

i'm adding the new method to the methods Array. Its being added fine in here. The problem is, when i make a reference of class C, and try to find that newly added method, it returns nothing. i.e.

```
a = C.new
a.id = 1
a.name = 'gaurav'
a.save
C.find_by_name('gaurav')
p a.methods.include?(:find_by_name)
```

returns **false**

Is there a way i could go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this has the feel of an overly-meta way of doing things to me - sure, rails does something like this, but that doesn't make it easily maintainable :). can you restructure your code to eliminate this problem? even if you find the "fix", it will still be hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the response and even i feel the same about the overly-meta thing.
But actually, this is one of my training exercises, i have to do it this way and code maintainence doesn't matter! :)

So, do you think something like this is possible, or how i can restructure my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the new methods are class methods defined for class C.
But 'a' is an instance of C so you don't see those methods.

This will return true

```
p a.class.methods.include?(:find_by_name)
```

EDITED

You are assuming that `methods << method` will add the method to the module but it will not do anything like that. So you need to explicitly define the method like this,

```
 ClassMethods = Module.new do
    def method_missing(method, *args, &block)      
      if method =~ /find_by_/
        add_search_method(method,*args)
        send(method, *args)
      else
        values.send "#{method}", &block
      end
    end

    def add_search_method(method, *args)
      define_singleton_method(method) do |*args|
        @@values.each do |obj|
          return obj if obj.send("#{method.to_s.split('_')[-1]}") == args[0]
        end
        nil
      end
    end
  end
```

Replace your ClassMethods definition with this one and C.methods will include your find by method.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish here but as Peter suggested in his comment, you probably need to restructure your code as this doesn't look too clean.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment Dipil, but the find_by_* methods have stopped working now!! :\